# Rails: Sanitising input from within the controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller, escaping

My Rails 3 app contains a form which isn't bound to a model.

I'm using `form_tag`, and my controller looks a little like this:

```
def results
    local_variable = params[:my_form_field].to_s
end
```

I do various other bits and pieces in the controller using `local_variable`, so obviously I would like to sanitise my form against "illegal" input that a nasty user might enter (particularly HTML tags, or even injections).

I really need to do this in the controller rather than in my view. Is there something similar to `to_s` I could use within the controller to remove these characters?

Thanks!

Comment: How about [this](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rails' Sanitize Helper: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

As long as you're not `eval`ing the contents of `local_variable` or executing it on the database, you should be safe.